# ECTS average mark?

Tags: united-kingdom, degree, grading, denmark

I studied in Denmark, where degree results are compared by average marks, amongst other things.

There are conversion tables for converting individual marks into ECTS marks, however I could not find out how this works for averages or how to compare precisely with a UK classification, for instance 1st, 2:1, 2:2, ...

My question is how do ECTS marks work for averages/overall degree results?

---

For example,

The mark 12 is translated to an ECTS A

The mark 10 is translated to an ECTS B

The mark 7 is translated to an ECTS C

and so on.

And you can find tables listing conversions between degree classifications and ECTS marks, for example [here](http://www.soas.ac.uk/studyabroad/current/file77183.pdf).

But for an average it is unrealistic to expect the top mark in every exam in a degree (21 marked exams and 4 pass/fail awards in my case) to get an A for the overall degree result. Or put a different way, without meaning any disrespect, I don't think all holders of UK 1st class degrees could have gotten the top mark 12 in all 21 exams without exception.

To give full details, I have a 5-year cand. scient. degree including one year of research with a public presentation and viva voce as final exam. I present this an MSc by research.

My average degree mark is 9.9 under the Danish 13-scale, which converts to 10.8 under the new 7-point scale with marks from -3 to 12. This is very respectable, the question is just how to explain/justify to employers that this exceeds the requirements for a 2:1 UK degree.

Comment: Perhaps look at distributions of the different marks?